# How can I have Excel predict when a budget runs out of money?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have been searching the web like crazy for what feels like weeks now and still can't find a solid answer.

I am attempting to have excel determine 90 days before a budget will run out of money.

In this situation I know what my total budget for the project is, what my hourly rate is and how many hours are being spent (therefore how much money is being spent) in a given week.

What I am trying to do is have a formula that takes the total budget as well as the average hours per day and determine when that budget will run dry.

Please let me know what additional information I need to supply and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Remaining budget is determined by : Starting Budget- (Hours expended * hourly rate). I am getting the hours expended by time sheets and the hourly rate is determined in advance. I am not quite sure what you mean by what does my data structure look like. I honestly don't even know where I could start in regards to a formula to even try.

Comment: This question is of the nature "how do I setup a worksheet to do ...." While this is something that can be done, it is not a good candidate for this site as the answer would need to be multiple chapters in a book.  The kernel of what you need is raw data, and expected data. Raw data is your budget, actual expenses, how much work has need done, etc.  Expected data is where you forecast the future.  If average hours per day is a good predictor. Then (Budget-actual)/(Daily average) gives how many days left until run out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on your data setup and how you keep remaining budget. If you just want to predict the end date based on the beginning date and the budget and rate it's pretty simple:

```
Begin Date  Budget  Hourly Rate  Hours/wk  Hours/day  End Date
5/1/2016     $500     $10         3         =D2/5     =WORKDAY(A2,(B2/(C2*E2)))
```

---

With your data structure:

```
Rate    Budget   Hours Expended Budget Remaining    Start Date  
$125    $500000     2000           $250000           1/1/2016
```

You can use

```
=WORKDAY(TODAY(),D2/((C2/(NETWORKDAYS(E2,TODAY())))*A2))
```

Comment: The way I have my data setup is:

Rate    Budget       Hours Expended   Budget Remaining  Start Date  
125.00    $500,000   2000                    B2-(a2*c2)               1/1/16

Comment: Updated to reflect your structure

Comment: Thanks so much. I was going nuts and creating all sorts of weird formulas that didn't work. This is much easier

Comment: If your question is answered please click the green checkmark to mark the  problem as solved.